# DotNetOpenAuth detect fetch request like google

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dotnetopenauth

With google, you can fetch the user's email like this:

```
var fetch = new FetchRequest();
fetch.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);
request.AddExtension(fetch);
```

and get it back like this:

```
var fetch = response.GetExtension<FetchResponse>();
string email = "";
if (fetch != null)
{
    email = fetch.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);
}
```

When writing a provider, how can I return the values asked for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OpenIdProviderWebForms sample that comes with DotNetOpenAuth includes returning user attributes.  Have you checked it out?